AWS Amplify Data Gen 2 returning stale data when owners updated directly in DynamoDB via Lambda function
I have created an AWS Amplify application with React Native and Amplify Data.  I have setup schemas for a team and members of a team.  The authentication that is used at the moment is an AWS Cognito user pool with the autorization added to the schema definition in Amplify Data:
authorization((allow) => [
  allow.ownersDefinedIn("owners"),
]),

When a new team member is added a lambda function is used to add the new team member to the team owners and also update the members owners array.  This is done directly in the DyanmoDB table.
When I make a call to return the team members (see below) stale data is returned:
const { data: teamMembers } = await team.members();

I have defined the following schemas:
const schema = a.schema({
  Team: a
    .model({
      code: a.string().required(),
      members: a.hasMany("Member", "teamId"),
      owners: a.string().array(),
    })
    .secondaryIndexes((index) => [index("code")])
    .authorization((allow) => [
      allow.ownersDefinedIn("owners"),
    ]), 

  Member: a
    .model({
      firstname: a.string().required(),
      surname: a.string().required(),
      fullName: a.string().required(),
      email: a.email().required(),
      teamId: a.id().required(),
      team: a.belongsTo("Team", "teamId"),
      owners: a.string().array(),
    })
    .authorization((allow) => [
      allow.ownersDefinedIn("owners"),
    ]),
});

I have also defined a lambda function to add a member to an existing team.  It does this by adding the new members user id to the owners array:
const updateInput: UpdateItemCommandInput = {
  TableName: tablename,
  Key: {
    id: team.id,
  },
  UpdateExpression: "set owners = :o",
  ConditionExpression: "id = :i",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":o": {
      L: [
        ...(team["owners"]["L"] as []),
        {
          S: memberId,
        },
      ],
    },
    ":i": team.id,
  },
  ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
};
const updateCommand = new UpdateItemCommand(updateInput);
return await ddbClient.send(updateCommand);

This is also repeated for each member of the team:
const updateInput: UpdateItemCommandInput = {
  TableName: tablename,
  Key: {
    id: entity.id,
  },
  UpdateExpression: "set owners = :o",
  ConditionExpression: "teamId = :t",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":o": {
      L: [...owners],
    },
    ":t": team.id,
  },
  ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
};
const updateCommand = new UpdateItemCommand(updateInput);
await ddbClient.send(updateCommand);

When I make a call to return the team members (see below) stale data is returned:
const { data: teamMembers } = await team.members();

However when I make a call to the observe query the correct data is returned:
client.models.Member.observeQuery({
  authMode: "userPool",
}).subscribe({
  next: ({ items, isSynced }) => {
    console.log("Member.observeQuery: ", items, isSynced);
  },
})

I have searched to see if this could be a caching problem but I have found no information related to this.
Any help greatly appreciated.

As part of the onboarding process, for the app we are working on, we were attempting to register two users at the same time.  This was the root cause of the issues we were experiencing.  When we changed the process to process one user at a time it resolved the issue.  I hope it helps someone else.
